# View history of Command Prompt in Window8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I want to get history from beginning in my command prompt just like it gives in terminal by Up and Down keys. F7 only gives me todays details. How can i get my complete history of commands in my command line. I search Google but not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Once a session ends, the history is lost by default.

Check this: [related answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/95404/is-there-a-global-persistent-cmd-history)

And as you pointed out correctly you may use the F7 key to view a history of all the commands that have been entered in that window.

But if you are using powershell then [you may follow this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/01/perserving-command-history-across-sessions/) to preserve history.

Comment: Is there any way to get all history from beginning or not in windows. If not then , is any other CLI in windows available juct like terminal in ubuntu?

Comment: As suggested in the *related answer* above. [You may use Clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/)